# question on lemma in Bushnell and Henniart, irreducible components of a particular induced representation

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I have a question on a lemma that appears in the book "The Local Langlands Conjecture for GL(2)" by Bushnell and Henniart.

The setting is as follows: we let $G = GL_2(k)$ where $k$ denotes a finite field, and we put

$$
B = \left\{ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&b\\ 0&d
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\in G\right\}, \quad
N = \left\{ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&b\\ 0&1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\in G\right\}, \quad
T = \left\{ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&0\\ 0&d
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\in G\right\}.
$$

If $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are characters of $k^*$, we can define the character $\chi = \chi_1\otimes \chi_2\;$ of $T$ by $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&0\\ 0&d
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\mapsto \chi_1(a)\chi_2(d)$; and this character can be regarded as a character of $B$ via the quotient $B\mapsto B/N\cong T$. The following lemma (**p. 45 in the book**) gives a characterisation of the irreducible components of the induced representation $Ind_B^G\; \chi$ of $G$.

**Lemma.** Let $\pi$ be an irreducible representation of $G$. The following conditions are equivalent:
(1) $\pi$ is equivalent to a $G$-subspace of $Ind_B^G\; \chi$, for some character $\chi$ of $T$;
(2) $\pi$ contains the trivial character of $N$.

In the proof one can find the following argument: for an irreducible representation $\sigma$ of $B$, to contain the trivial character of $N$ is equivalent to be the inflation of a character of $T$.

This statement is not clear for me. Anyone who could explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in thinking that you understand the statement of the lemma and only don't understand the sentence about inflation?

Inflation is simply the process of extending a representation of $T$ to a representation of $B$ by allowing $N$ to act trivially. Then the goal of the proof is to show that $N$ acts trivially if and only if $\pi$ contains the trivial character when restricted to $N$, if and only if $\pi$ is of the form $Ind_B^G\ \chi$.

Comment: Yes, in fact from the context I assumed that inflation is defined in that way. I found it a bit strange that many times in the book they don't call it inflation but just to regard a character of some quotient group of $G$ as a character of $G$ itself. 

What was not clear for me is really the particular statement that one can find in the proof: an irreducible representation $\sigma$ of $B$ contains the trivial character of $N$ if and only if it is the inflation of a character. I think I have a solution now for this problem, perhaps you can tell me if you agree.

Comment: Let $\sigma: B\to GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation containing the unit character of $N$; so let us say that $W\subseteq V$ is a line on which $N$ acts trivially. Than $V$ is the sum (not necc. direct sum) of the lines $gW$ where $g$ runs trough $B$ (use the irreducibility of $V$). But $N$ acts trivial on every such line so in particular trivial on $V$. So the action of $B$ on $V$ quotients through $B/N \cong T$, which is an abelian group. Hence $\sigma$ is the inflation of a character of $T$.

Comment: So whenever I have an irreducible representation $K\to GL(V)$ of an arbitrary finite group $K$ that contains a normal subgroup $M$, then the isotypic components of the restriction $N\to GL(V)$ are permuted among themselves by elements of $K$. Moreover, these isotypic components contain the same number of irreducible representations (in a direct sum of this isotypic component) and all the irreducible representations of $N$ appearing are conjugated ones (exactly one conjugacy class of representations). Do you agree?

Comment: That's basically right, but I think the easiest argument is to use Frobenius reciprocity. If $\pi$ is of the form $Ind_B^G\ \chi$ then $\chi$ is a subrepresentation of $Res_B^G\ \pi$, hence (restricting further to $N$) $\pi$ contains the trivial character of $N$. Conversely, if $\pi$ contains the trivial character of $N$ then so does some irreducible subrepresentation of $Res_B^G\ \pi$. But then $\pi$ contains something irreducible and inflated from $T$.

Comment: Yes it is the same proof given in the book but my questions regards only your last sentence: why the irreducible subrepresentation of $Res_B^G \pi$, the one that contains the trivial character of $N$, is necessarily an inflated character of $T$.

Comment: Ah, OK; sorry, I misread your first comment. Yes, your argument is absolutely fine. The more general viewpoint that you mention is what's called Clifford theory. Restricting to a normal subgroup of a finite group gives precisely one $K$-orbit of irreducible representations, as you say, and so knowing that one of them is trivial is enough. (Seeing as you're reading a book about groups over $p$-adic fields, it's probably worth pointing out that this is often the case more generally, e.g. for topological groups $N\leq G$ with $G/N$ abelian, or for certain nice $p$-adic groups like $GL$ and $SL$.)

Comment: Ok thank you for your comments and time!